# Как реализовать постепенную загрузку маркеров?

Tags: google-maps-api

Из-за большого числа данных и сложности условия их выборки, встала задача постранично подгрузить данные. Как это можно сделать? Загрузка в цикле для аякса совсем не вариант, т.к. она синхронна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может помочь рекурсия. Например:

```
function downloadMarkers(){
    $.ajax(
        ...
        success: function(){
            downloadMarkers()
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Не может, а очень даже поможет. И я бы рекомендовал написать это в стиле _jQuery1.7+_ с использованием промисов